# Pushback elements of other arrays

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I created two arrays A and B, the array C should store the first elements of A and B.
Ex : A={1,2,3}, B={4,5,6}, C must be {1,4,2,5,3,6}. 
My program doesn't show anything after the input of my arrays.
This is my loop :

```
for(int i(0);i<3;i++){
        C.push_back(A[i]);
        C.push_back(B[i]);
}

for(int i(0);i<6;i++){
        std::cout << C[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: [Works fine for me.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3097dc7e5809998c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> B = {4,5,6};
    std::vector<int> C;
    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
    {
        C.push_back(A[i]);
        C.push_back(B[i]);
    }

    for (int i(0); i < 6; i++)
    {
        std::cout << C[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can change it to:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A(3);
    std::vector<int> B(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> A[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> B[i];
    }
    std::vector<int> C;
    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
    {
        C.push_back(A[i]);
        C.push_back(B[i]);
    }

    for (int i(0); i < 6; i++) 
    {
        std::cout << C[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Initilize n = length(A) + length(B)
vector<int> C[n];
for(int i=0;i<3;i+=2){
       C.push_back(A[i]);
       C.push_back(B[i]);
}
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    cout<<C[i];
}
```

[image]